# How do I report non-fatal errors using Android Crittercism SDK

Tags: android, report, crittercism

In my app, I'm catching an NPE then handling it grateful. Still, I would like to know when this happens using Crittercism. Is this possible?

EDIT: I.e., is it possible to make Crittercism think there was a crash?

Answer (score 0):

Logging handled exceptions:
`Crittercism.logHandledException(exception);`